# How to join current cast session? CAF Android Multiple sender app v3

Tags: android, casting

Currently I am successfully able to cast a video to the chrome cast. However when I use the second device and connect to the same device when casting from first device is in progress. It kills cast session on the first device and doesn't connect on the second one.

Is there any way to get the status of the receiver?

This usually happens when I call following on second device.

> remoteMediaClient.load(mediaInfo, mediaOptions);

I tried getting the active input state from cast session but it keeps saying ACTIVE_INPUT_STATE_UNKNOWN. There is no way I can get the status even via remoteMediaClient. Any help would be appreciated.